# Access nested optional properties with bracket notation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm learning TypeScript. I created my type for a WhatsApp message object, which sends some properties depending on the type of message:

```
// (edited and completed according to wonderflame comment)
type WhatsAppMessageObject = {
  id: string,
  from: string,
  type: string,
  audio?: {
    id?: string,
    mime_type?: string
  },
  document?: {
    caption?: string,
    filename: string,
    sha256: string,
    mime_type: string,
    id: string
  },
  text?: {
    body?: string
  },
  // More types. Cutted for brevity
}

type MessageData = {
  type: string,
  id?: string,
  mimeType?: string,
  optionId?: string;
  message?: string;
  normalizedMessage?: string;
}
```

So, I identified some "file" messages, that are messages that comes with some kind of file (document, audio, image, etc.). When some of this messages is sended to my backend, the object includes the property, i.e:

```json
from: "someNumber",
  id: "someId",
  timestamp: "1690317478",
  type: "image",
  image: {
    mime_type: "image/jpeg",
    sha256: "someSha256",
    id: "someId",
  },
  text?: {
    body?: string
  },
  time
};
```

So, what I want is to access this properties and do different stuff if its a file message, a text message or an interactive message:

```
// Simplified for brevity (edited and completed according to wonderflame comment)

function handleMessageType(messageObject: WhatsAppMessageObject) {
  
  const {from, id: messageId} = messageObject
  const messageType = messageObject.type;
  const fileMessages: Array<keyof WhatsAppMessageObject> = ["audio", "document"];

  let messageData: MessageData = {
    type: messageType,
  };

  // If is a file message
  if (fileMessages.includes(messageType as keyof WhatsAppMessageObject)) {
    messageData.id = messageObject[messageType as keyof WhatsAppMessageObject]?.id;
    messageData.mimeType = messageObject[messageType as keyof WhatsAppMessageObject]?.mime_type;
    // TODO: Implement saving the files
  } 

  if(messageType === 'text') {
    messageData.message = messageObject.text!.body
    messageData.normalizedMessage = normalizeString(messageObject.text!.body)
  }

  return {messageId, from, messageData}
}

// Takes a string, make all letters lowercase and removes all special characters
function normalizeString(str = '') {
  let normalizedStr = str.toLowerCase()
    .normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
  return normalizedStr
}
```

The types, like " as keyof WhatsAppMessageObject" was suggested by chatGPT, but I couldn't solve by any means "Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ body?: string | undefined; }' " (line 14 in handleMessageType function snippet, same for line 15 "mime_type").

Please, what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include missing variables or remove them if they are redundant

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot find anything redundant. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please remove the other errors [here](https://tsplay.dev/NnBRvN)

Comment: Oh I understand now. Sorry and thank you. I edited my code completing it. The two errors that I couldn't solve remain. [Here's the link](https://tsplay.dev/w2kVrN).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK3nzW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: What's this magic? I love it, thank you so much. Is there any resource that you can recommend me to start studying TypeScript?

Comment: Honestly, the best resource is the official documentation. I'll point out to the relevant pages in my answer.

Comment: oh, I forgot to write the answer, sorry. Will do soon

Answer (score 1):

Let's define an array of `WhatsAppMessageObject`'s keys that are `FileMessage`:

```
// string[]
const fileMessages = [
  'audio',
  'document',
]
```

. The compiler widens the type of the array to the primitive. The `string[]` is not suitable for us and to prevent widening let's use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in combination with the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator to ensure the type-checking:

```
// readonly ["audio", "document"]
const fileMessages = [
  'audio',
  'document',
] as const satisfies readonly  (keyof WhatsAppMessageObject)[];
```

Now, using the [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) let's create a type for the `FileMessage`, which should be a union of `fileMessages`'s elements:

```
// "audio" | "document"
type FileMessage = typeof fileMessages[number];
```

Since `fileMessage` is an array/tuple, its keys are `number` and by using `number` as a key we can get the union of all its values.

We will also need a custom [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to ensure that the passed variable is a `FileMessage`:

```
const isFileMessage = (arg: unknown):arg is FileMessage => {
  return typeof arg === "string" && fileMessages.includes(arg as FileMessage)
}
```

Thus, we can use this type guard in your function:

```
function handleMessageType(messageObject: WhatsAppMessageObject) {
  const { from, id: messageId } = messageObject;
  const messageType = messageObject.type;


  let messageData: MessageData = {
    type: messageType,
  };

  // If is a file message
  if (isFileMessage(messageType)) {
    messageData.id =
      messageObject[messageType]?.id;
    messageData.mimeType =
      messageObject[messageType]?.mime_type;
    // TODO: Implement saving the files
  }

  if (messageType === 'text') {
    messageData.message = messageObject.text!.body;
    messageData.normalizedMessage = normalizeString(messageObject.text!.body);
  }

  return { messageId, from, messageData };
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gFgQ2AZwIJjAWQs5CDmEA8gEYBWEAxsFALxQDeAUFFAJYAmAXFMsAE5sAdvgDcLKADN+AewC2PPoJHjWoSIoHCxEhAFcObGQH4ezVq06neWlRNZy2ciAH11Ea0u2qoAXx8cMpR6zkLA1uYWlAhgwEZCnrY6FlJsADYQQgjOmsrJFsiIAEwArABsud72UI7ObuAQlXYpnE35-hLAEAAe4WbVJDIcIIl5Ph2sAPSTUJgy-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-BwcIeZZODoapRJvcg7ypeDCConljAkjgfBkikiOWb4qKklJNNhKCFIEhoVJ0pxXHQ6o5x+IhbiIHhQTkZcIE5XgEGOERqzgaBJQyZAJF8QNLC4xSLyQht6FpLpelpYTSLYu5xPC5DZONYA0J6YAAEJlkGYYNKSiBtMRfhkVRDEsUjegyoq9EIHnJJ+PSu8st6PKCpAE1xhCqAywrKsf3C8EAOkeQAPCoi-HEYKmFshA1UFR4W3wSbFugFE0igLCun4QU0hkZM-WiZBNpPfq3JkQ5KS23hIEoNgUSFRB+AQag-UCvchAPIkoDqlEGqavIlSUJ5aXij8sP+pFAaq4GniUao0JkAAZI6-TWAUICVacUmWAHKpx2kADkbVueLkYWZd3pxyYqQAHT0AAGABmZnmYAWiZtmykkHlJjWqAIZ6iQBsrGHyrhzFgdmpggA)

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved although not the way I wanted... anyway, maybe someone can help my solution useful, although not optimal.

So, basically was filling the function with "magic strings" (something I don't like very much, but anyway, is not that Meta will have hundreds of message types):

```
function handleMessageType(messageObject: WhatsAppMessageObject) {
  try {
    // extract the message ID, phone number and type of message from the payload
    const {from, type: messageType, id: messageId} = messageObject

    const otherMessages = ["button", "order"]; // TODO: This types of messages doesn't have an implementation yet

    let messageData: MessageData = { type: messageType };

    if (messageType === 'audio' || messageType === 'document' || messageType === 'image' || messageType === 'sticker' || messageType === 'video') {
      messageData.id = messageObject[messageType]!.id;
      messageData.mimeType = messageObject[messageType]!.mime_type;
      // TODO: Implement saving the files
    } else if(messageType === 'interactive') {
      const interactiveType = messageObject[messageType]!.type;
      messageData.optionId = messageObject[messageType]![interactiveType]!.id
    } else if (messageType === 'text') {
      messageData.message = messageObject.text!.body
      messageData.normalizedMessage = normalizeString(messageObject.text!.body)
    }

    return {messageId, from, messageData}
  } catch (err: any) { 
      err.name = 'messageTypeException'
      throw err
  }
}
```

Notice that I changed the "type" property for "messageType". That's because "type" is a reserved keyword.

Anyway, I hope someone come with a better, more escalable solution.